# Can I create game objects from outside monobehaviour

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to instantiate in a class that is not a monobevaviour.

At the moment I call a helper class to do it but I want to reduce dePendency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do this:

```
MonoBehaviour.Instantiate(ObjectPrefab);
```

This is because Instantiate is actually static in the MonoBehaviour class.

Comment: This gives me a when I try run it:
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
UnityEngine.Object+MarshalledUnityObject.ThrowNullExceptionObjectImpl (System.Object obj) (at <cd14705e8f094afcb566740ab5e8c02d>:0)

Answer (score 0):

You can instantiate `GameObject`s or anything that derives from GameObject.  `ScriptableObject`s are very useful.

If you don't want the Update/Start/Awake/etc. methods that are part of `GameObject`s, then you can use constructors of any objects that you want to Instantiate and/or create your own `Instantiate` methods.